# Sollte die Bedingung in diesen Beispielsätzen erneut negiert werden?

Tags: negation

> Du brauchst zwingend einen neuen Haarschnitt und neue Kleidung. Also:
>
> (a) Komm nicht wieder, bevor du beides hast.

oder

> (b) Komm nicht wieder, bevor du nicht beides hast.

Welcher Satz ist richtig? (a) scheint mir logisch korrekt, doch mein Sprachgefühl neigt zu (b) …

Comment: Ich persönlich habe mit verneinenden Konditionalsätzen, die das Wort »bevor« enthalten, ein generelles Problem. Daher würde ich den Satz wie folgt formulieren: »Komm erst wieder, wenn du beides hast.« Kein »bevor«, keine Verneinung. Alles gut.

Comment: Logisch scheint mir den zweiten satz ganz falsch, aber Sprachen sind ja nicht immer logisch. In anderen Sprachen, die ich kenne, ist nur die erste Konstruktion möglich.

Comment: (b) wäre richtig, wenn du "solange" verwendest.

Comment: Doppelte Verneinungen in der Sprache funktionieren nicht wie in der Mathematik/Logik. Sie dienen eher der *Verstärkung* der Verneinung als ihrer Negation. Siehe z.B. das gern gebrauchte "Das wird ja nie nicht klappen"

Comment: @tofro: Wird vielleicht in Bayern gern gebraucht, in Preußen kannst Du das schlicht nicht hören.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hab' ja auch nicht vom "gern hören", sondern vom "gern gebrauchen" gesprochen ;) Der berühmteste "nie nicht"-Verwender ist sicher der brave Soldat Schwejk, und das war sozusagen ein Österreicher.

Comment: @tofro: Und sprachlich sind die Österreicher, die das gerne gebrauchen, ja halberte Bayern. Was ich sagen wollte: Es ist ein Regionalismus, also etwas, was man einem Sprachlerner nicht unbedingt vermittelt, bzw. wenn er nachfragt, erläutert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beides ist nicht falsch, allerdings ist die doppelte Negation nicht notwendig.

Duden.de formuliert es noch ziemlich angenehm:

> Bisweilen drücken temporale Nebensätze, die mit den Bindewörtern bevor, bis, eh[e] eingeleitet werden, eine Bedingung aus. Wenn diese Nebensätze dann von einem verneinten Hauptsatz abhängen, kann der durch bevor, bis oder ehe eingeleitete Nebensatz zur Not auch selbst noch verneint werden.

[Quelle](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/negation)

Answer (score 1):

Die [Antwort von @Kaj](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33532/19330) ist vollkommen richtig (und schön kurz). Ich wollte aber noch etwas auf die logische Korrektheit und eventuelle historische Entstehung eingehen.

---

### Vom rein logischen Standpunkt her

Wenn man die Verneinung herausnimmt und die Satzteile tauscht, kommt der eigentliche Sinn heraus:

Der eigentliche Sinn des Satzes ist folgender (ohne Verneinung):

> Habe beides, bevor du wieder kommst.

Wenn man das nun einfach zurücktauscht, kommt aber ein falscher Sinn heraus:

> Komme wieder, bevor du beides hast.

Dadurch ergibt sich, dass das Vertauschen ähnlich einer Verneinung ist. Um den Sinn der Aussage zu erhalten, muss man also beim Vertauschen zusätzlich *eine* weitere Verneinung unterbringen, damit diese sich gegenseitig aufheben:

> Komme nicht wieder, bevor du beides hast.

Beim Verneinen beider Satzteile ergibt sich mit der *Negation* durch die Vertauschung der Satzteile eine dreifache Verneinung, die sich zu einer einfachen Verneinung zusammenfassen lässt (zwei davon heben sich gegenseitig auf). Dadurch wird aber die eigentliche Aussage verneint und es kommt das Gegenteil heraus.

### Vom sprachlichen Standpunkt her

Sprachlich ist [laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/negation) (*Danke @Kaj!*) beides erlaubt und somit auch korrekt. Die doppelte Verneinung hebt sich in diesem Fall *nicht* gegenseitig auf, sondern verstärkt die Aussage.

#### Mögliche Geschichtliche Erklärung

Wenn man *bevor* durch *solange* ersetzt, muss der zweite Teil auch verneint werden, um die Aussage zu erhalten (in diesem Fall hebt sich die doppelte Verneinung auf).

In der Umgangssprache haben sich diese beiden Formulierungen über die Jahrhunderte vermischt und die zweite Negation hat sich beim *bevor* mit eingeschlichen; auch weil einem die Aussage klar ist, ohne darüber nachzudenken. Herausgekommen ist dadurch die logisch schwachsinnige, aber durch die häufige Verwendung sprachlich richtige Formulierung.

Ähnlich verhielt es sich übrigens beim eigentlich schwachsinnigen Wort *nichtsdestotrotz*. Dies hat sich im 19. Jahrhundert aus *nichtsdestoweniger* und *trotzdem* in der Alltagssprache gebildet und hat seinen Weg in die Schriftsprache und letztlich auch [in den Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nichtsdestotrotz) geschafft. (siehe auch [Herkunft von *nichtsdestotrotz* der Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache e. V.](http://gfds.de/nichtsdestotrotz/)

Comment: »Koane doppelten Verneinungen heben sich nie ned auf«, würde der Bayer sagen ;)

Comment: Der logische Standpunkt klingt sehr nach Mathematik. Da läuft es mir eiskalt den Rücken runter. Bitte ziehe diese schöne Sprache nicht in die Mathematik. ;)

Comment: @Jan: ;)

.@KajTorvaldGrey: Schöne Sprache, da gebe ich dir vollkommen recht! Ich ziehe sie ja auch nicht in die Mathematik, sondern _nur_ in die Logik (das ist zwar ein Teilgebiet, macht für mich aber dennoch einen Unterschied). ;) In der Tat haben Logik und Sprache in einigen Dingen sehr viel gemein.